# Passing a variable as Parameter

Tags: ssis

I have a scenario where i need to pass an text file or excel file column as an parameter to my Sql Query in SSIS Package.

My Text or excel file has a column called Policy_no and it has more than 1000+ policy_no(EX: 12358685). i have an Sql script ***select * from main_table where policy_no = ?***. And that that '?' has to be come from my package variable(txt or excel ).

Instead of manually writing script for each and every policy,  how can we achieve this through SSIS.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with the results of your query? I ask this because I wonder if there might be a better way to get to your end goal

Comment: @Billinkc : i would like to store the results in Excel file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to loop through each row in your file and run the query against each individual value, you can use a Data Flow task to read your text file and load the policy numbers in an ADO Recordset (declared as a package variable). Next, you'd use a Foreach Loop Container to iterate through the recordset, loading each policy number in turn into a second variable and then executing your query and doing whatever other work is needed.

See [Use a Recordset Destination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879316.aspx) in MSDN for an overview and example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EXECUTE SQL TASK** (Connect Excel with OLE DB Connection) to get "Policy_no" data from Excel, then store the result into a variable, say:policyNoGroup, whose data type should be **Object**, then use **For Each Loop** to loop though variable policyNoGroup, see the example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS